# DataBinding and form closing event

Tags: .net, vb.net, binding

I have a binding object for a textbox as follows

```
Private withevents m_ShortNameBinding As Binding
```

using the BindingSource, I have bind the ShortName property to the textbox as follows

```
m_ShortNameBinding = txtShortName.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_SampleSource, "ShortName", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

I also handled the BindingComplete event like below

```
Private Sub m_ShortNameBinding_BindingComplete(sender As Object, e As BindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles m_ShortNameBinding.BindingComplete
        If Not e.BindingCompleteState = BindingCompleteState.Success Then
            ErrorProvider.SetError(txtShortName, e.ErrorText)
        End If
End Sub
```

By the above way I try to validate the textbox should not capture more than 8 chars. It works perfectly all right.

Unless the State of the binding is Success, it is not allow me close the Form. How can I skip the validation while closing form or give me some other approach to achieve the same?

Thanks...

Comment: in `textbox's` which `event` you are validating ?

Comment: i request you to validate on `txtShortName_Keydown`

Comment: I am not handle any event of Textbox. By binding the "ShortName" property to the "Text" Property of the TextBox, and the property throws the exception.